# Updating the list in the ListFragment (parent) with changes in DialogFragment AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have one ListFragment called **MeasurementList** which displays all registered measurement data. To register new measurement data Im using DialogFragment named **NewMeasurement** with custom made view in AlertDialog with required UI controls to be filled out.

Now, I need an elegant solution to update the measurement list in the ListFragment with the new registered measurement after the DialogFragment is dismissed. I don't want to update the list from the database, but rather just adding the newly created Measurement object to the list. I have tried to follow Android guidelines on how to make fragments communicate with activities through callback interfaces  ([Creating event callbacks to the activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)). The MeasurementList passes its reference to the NewMeasurement so it can call it back after registering new measurement. The problem is how to save the listener reference in the Bundle in the NewMeasurement.newInstance() method. It mainly saved the primitive data types and not objects like in my case.

Any tip and suggestions would be appreciated.

**MeasurementList.java**

```
public class MeasurementList extends ListFragment implements OnMeasurementSetListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addMeasurement:
                NewMeasurement newMeasurementDialog = NewMeasurement.newInstance(this);
                newMeasurementDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "newMeasurementDialog");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasurementSet(Measurement measurement) {
        MeasurementAdapter listAdapter = (MeasurementAdapter) getListAdapter();
        listAdapter.add(measurement);
    }
}
```

**OnMeasurementSetListener.java**

```
public interface OnMeasurementSetListener {
    public abstract void onMeasurementSet(Measurement measurement);
}
```

**NewMeasurement.java**

```
public class NewMeasurement extends DialogFragment
{
    private OnMeasurementSetListener mListener;

    public static NewMeasurement newInstance(OnMeasurementSetListener listener) 
    {
        NewMeasurement nm = new NewMeasurement();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("listener", listener); // NOT WORKING
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = factory.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_new_measurement, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.title_alert_dialog_new_weight);
        builder.setIconAttribute(R.drawable.add);
        builder.setView(v);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, this);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, this);
        return builder.create();

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            mListener = (OnMeasurementSetListener) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("listener");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can try to handle this onAttach method by setting new measurement it will create a call back to your activity.

```
public class MeasurementList extends ListFragment implements OnMeasurementSetListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addMeasurement:
                NewMeasurement newMeasurementDialog = NewMeasurement.newInstance(this);
                newMeasurementDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "newMeasurementDialog");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasurementSet(Measurement measurement) {
        MeasurementAdapter listAdapter = (MeasurementAdapter) getListAdapter();
        listAdapter.add(measurement);
    }
}
```

**NewMeasurement.java**

```
public class NewMeasurement extends DialogFragment {

    public interface OnMeasurementSetListener {
        public abstract void onMeasurementSet(Measurement measurement);
    }

    private OnMeasurementSetListener onMeasurementSetListener;
    private Measurement currentMeasurement;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            Measurement measurement = new Measurement();
            measurement.s = "fragment";
            onMeasurementSetListener = (OnMeasurementSetListener) activity;
            setMeasurement(measurement);

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement onMeasurementSetListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Fragment Dialog");
        builder.setIconAttribute(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.app_name, new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.app_name, new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }

    private void setMeasurement(Measurement measurement) {
        currentMeasurement = measurement;
        onMeasurementSetListener.onMeasurementSet(measurement);
    }

}
```

**Sample Measurement.java**

```
public class Measurement {
    public String s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your solution is basing on communication between NewMeasurement and the Activity, not MeasurementList, which is the parent/caller of the NewMeasurement dialog. Do you suggest that NewMeasurement communicates the newly created measurement to the Activity, and activity again communicate this to the MeasurementList?

Comment: I believe the answer on my question is that fragments should not talk to each other directly, but through Activity. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, from your **DialogFragment**, you can call back to the **Activity** that contains your **ListFragment**, calling a newly created method, within the **Activity** that updates your **ListFragment**.